# How to add an image using css in asp mvc 2?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, html.actionlink

I want to add a clickable image using a css class to an anchor tag in an asp mvc 2 application and leave the url section empty(since I have javascript code to load a pop up based on the id given to the anchor tag).

Currently my code is :

```
<%= Html.ImageActionLink(null, null, "~/UI/Forms/Css/Images/get-reservation.png", null, new { @Id = "getReservation" }, new { @Class = "image" })%>
```

**Info:** I added the Id, since I am using javascript to load a pop up when the getReservation id is clicked. The image class just adds padding.

current css code :

```
.image
{
   padding-left: 10px;  
}
```

What I want:

To remove the path below from my ImageActionLink helper

"~/UI/Forms/Css/Images/get-reservation.png"

and define a css class:

```
.get-reservation
{
background: url('images/get-reservation.png') no-repeat center;
height: 20px;
width:20px;
}
```

and do something like this:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("#", null, new { @Class = "get-reservation image" }, new { @Id = "getReservation" })%>
```

But what I get in the browser is something like this :(And the image fails to appear.)

[image]

Expected outcome:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ActionLink in this case is unnecessary, just use regular image or div

```
<div class="get-reservation image" id="getReservation"></div>
```

You can add this to the style, to make it more like a link:

```
border: none;
cursor: pointer; /* hand cursor */
```

Finally, when you select it to add the click handler, if you were using `$('a.get-reservation')` change to `$('div.get-reservation')` or simply `$('.get-reservation')`

Comment: Helpers are useful for dynamic elements, this one is static, so you really shouldn't use them

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do this:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("", "#", null, new { @Id = "getReservation", @Class = "get-reservation image" })%>
```

Note that the first parameter is the text to show, that's why you got a '#' on screen before. The third parameter is a null RouteValues, and the fourth is for the additional html attributes.

Here you have the method definition: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx

Hope to have helped you. Cheers

Comment: I am getting this error: Server Error in '/' Application.

Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: linkText [Thanks for trying]

Comment: Mmm, could you try sending `&nbsp;` instead of `""`?